# How do I change the value stored in a image file in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, image, file

I save my first image and it loads, but when I save the second, the image of the button stays the same as the first image I saved. Can someone show me how to have that files value be able to change?

Here is the code that runs when someone picks an image:

```
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        // choose a name for your image
        let fileName = "image.jpg"
        // create the destination file url to save your image
        let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        // get your UIImage jpeg data representation and check if the destination file url already exists
        if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 1.0),
            !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
            do {
                // writes the image data to disk
                try data.write(to: fileURL)
                print("file saved")
            } catch {
                print("error saving file:", error)
            }
        }

        if let image = getSavedImage(named: "image.jpg") { Button1.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        }
```

And here is my code for when the view loads:

```
 if let image = getSavedImage(named: "image.jpg") {
        Button1.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: You never save the second image because you only save an image if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

As @rmaddy mentioned you already saved image thats why image not replaced. but if you want on tap of button image will be change you need to do some extra work, you need to check if `image.jpg` exist then add new image with diff name.To check image exist use this method, This method return bool value and path of the file if file exist.So on these two values you can remove your existing image or create new image with different name, according to your code behaviour.

```
static func isFileExit(filename: String) -> (fileExist: Bool? , path: URL?) {


    if let dir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) {
        let filepath =  URL(fileURLWithPath: dir.absoluteString).appendingPathComponent(filename)
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filepath.path) {
            print("FILEAVAILABLE")
            return (true, filepath)
        }

    }

    return (false,nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saving your images only if the image doesn't exist, so when you try to save the second image, its not being saved because the first image already exists.

```
//you should double check what you're doing here
    if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 1.0),
                !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
                do {
                    // writes the image data to disk
                    try data.write(to: fileURL)
                    print("file saved")
                } catch {
                    print("error saving file:", error)
                }
            }
```